# Light photon wavelength not equal?

Tags: photons

Added reference points from photo from this article:

https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/what-shape-is-a-photon

As you can see in the reference photo the order of intensity is highest at point A (bottom) then point B (left) then point C (right) then point D (top).

Wouldn’t this mean that the wave is longer between points A and D (the Y axis with respect to photon as in photo) than B and C (the X axis)?
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what the image is about and what you're asking. I can't tell anything from the title and text of the question. Please also reduce the size of the photo by a factor of 2, otherwise it's unwieldy to scroll back and forth past it.

Comment: To on @BenCrowell comments on the size, most of the picture is just black. You can do a significant amount of cropping without losing any information.

Comment: In this diagram, I could just assume that the photon is shifted to the down left side. I do not know of a way to explain this otherwise. Could you explain more to us about this "hologram"?

Answer (score 2):

The intensity is not related to the wavelength if that is what you mean when you say length.  The intensity is proportional to the number of photons.